# Spring Boot CORS not working with React app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, web, cors

So as the title mentions, I have a spring boot backend that serves a REST API to a React front end. I have been getting numerous CORS issues, and have tried multiple methods. I am not an expert on spring-security but would really appreciate some help solving this issue.

My CORS config

```
private static final String [] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        // -- Swagger UI v2
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/_ah/warmup",
        "/ae/test",
        // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


    http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider,userDetailsService));

}

CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    //config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("localhost:3000"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowCredentials(false);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not annotated with `@Bean`, so I do not think Spring is automatically instantiating or injecting this configuration.

Try annotating the method with `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("localhost:3000"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowCredentials(Boolean.FALSE);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```